# Как интегрировать личные сообщения с соц. сетей в бота?

Tags: telegram-bot, соцсети

Хочу создать бота, целью которого будет являться пересылка сообщений из социальных сетей и мессенджеров, таких как Вконтакте, Одноклассники, Facebook, Viber, WhatsApp и т.п. через бота, с возможностью ответа из Телеграмма. Что для этого нужно и осуществима ли эта идея вообще?

Comment: Ты вообще не разбираешься в этой теме?

Comment: Я себе такое сделал, из вк и slack сообщения идут в телеграм и я там отвечаю на них, в viber точно так не сделать, остальные не пробовал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала вам нужно что-нибудь, на чём будет работать ваш бот. Возможные варианты:

1. Ваш персональный компьютер. Для непрерывной работы бота вам нужно будет держать компьютер всё время включённым.
2. Свой сервер, например на [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/).
3. Какая-нибудь облачная платформа приложений, например [Heroku](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku).

Для простоты рассмотрим первый вариант. Рассмотрим случай **пересылки сообщений из ВКонтакте** в Телеграмм. Ваша программа должна будет периодически (скажем раз в семь секунд) посылать запросы на сервер ВКонтакте для определения появления новых сообщений. У ВКонтакте есть [API](https://vk.com/dev/first_guide). Запрос к `API` — это обычный [HTTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) запрос. HTTP запросы можно посылать из большинства языков программирования, однако наиболее подходящим в нашем случае является язык [Python](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python). Приятным бонусом этого языка является наличие библиотек для более приятной работы с API ВКонтакте, например [этой](https://github.com/python273/vk_api). Вот [пример](https://habrahabr.ru/post/326312/) работы с этой библиотекой.

Далее, допустим ваша программа научилась получать сообщения из ВКонтакте. Следующим этапом является **отправка сообщений в Телеграмм**. У Телеграмма тоже есть [API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api). И, конечно, для Python тоже есть [библиотека](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI) для удобной работы. Например, в этой библиотеке есть метод `send_message`, который ваша программа будет вызывать, когда бот будет получить новое сообщение из ВКонтакте.

Далее, допустим ваш бот смог переслать сообщение из ВКонтакте в Телеграмм. Пользователь Телеграмм увидел это сообщение и ответил на него. Вашему боту нужно **получить сообщение из Телеграмма**. Можно сделать это немного более аккуратно и вместо проверки новых сообщений каждые семь секунд написать функцию, которая будет вызываться каждый раз, когда вашему боту пишут сообщение в Телеграмме. О том, чтобы эта функция вызывалась, [позаботится](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#writing-your-first-bot) упомянутая библиотека `pyTelegramBotAPI`.